# Seeing the internals of an R function as it runs

Tags: r, performance, refactoring

I have written an R function that is much too slow and needs to be refactored. My function also contains calls to other functions in packages (specifically `TraMineR`). In fact, my function is so slow that it doesn't finish, not even in 20-30 hours on a new Macbook Pro.

Is there a way to see the internals of the function as it runs? If I could see each command as it is passed to R, I could better assess where the actual slowness occurs.

Comment: Normally, one would profile the function (`?Rprof`). However, if a function is that slow it should be possible to identify the most time consuming operations by simply looking at the code. Have you made sure to avoid the cardinal sins detailed in the R-inferno?

Comment: check out the lineprof package https://github.com/hadley/lineprof

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, or knowing the size of your data, how can we determine whether it's truly slow?  Processing 1e12 data points is rather different from processing 1e4 data points!